# JSOM bulk SP.ListItem creation: get created Ids

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, splistitem, jsom

I'm using this approach to bulk SP.ListItem creation:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('listTitle');
myObj.forEach(function(d,i)
{
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); 

        fields.forEach(function(f){
            this.oListItem.set_item(f, d[f]);
        });

    this.oListItem.update();

    ctx.load(this.oListItem);
});


ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
    Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
);

function successHandler(data) {
    window.data = data; //==> see picture below
}

function errorHandler(s,c,e) {
    console.log("==ERR==", s,c,e)
}

//references: 
//http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/batch-operations-using-javascript.html
//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx
```

[image]

Can I rely on `data.$1L_0` property as the container of response object items?
Is there a strict JSOM approach to get the ids?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the ids from `data.$1L_0` with the actual ids from your list. If they are same, then you can rely on `data.$1L_0`.

Anyway following JSOM approach, you can flow:

Add items in a array, then get ids from it using `get_id()`.

```
var itemArray = [];
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Project');


for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!' + i);
    oListItem.update();
    itemArray[i] = oListItem;
    clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
}

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);


function onQuerySucceeded() {
    itemArray.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.get_id());
    });
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

**PS:** Above example is already given in **Vardhaman Deshpande's** blog. I have just added the following section.

```
itemArray.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.get_id());
    });
```